# How to compare arrays and objects to find a match PHP

Tags: php

My first question is, how do I search values of my array inside the objects array [words] and return object if match is found?

How do I search for a better match? In the example below, second object is a better match with 2 words in common, rather than first with only 1 match.

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => green
    [2] => love
    [3] => sandro
)


stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [words] => Array
                (
                    [0] => green
                    [1] => blue
                )

            [html] => html+img+link+code
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [words] => Array
                (
                    [0] => love
                    [1] => sex
                    [2] => blue
                )

            [html] => html+img+link+code
        )

)
```

Code I tried:

```
foreach ($ads_arr as $ad) {
  print_r(array_intersect($ad->words,$words_arr));
}
```

Comment: you should provide some code example instead of only the output

Comment: Why do you say that the second object is a better match? They both have two matches. Green + Blue, and Love + Blue.

Comment: @MalcolmDiggs yes you are right! sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for`loop for your case, but you should consider defining real php class (not `stdClass` ) and implement some methods to help you.

```
foreach($main_std as $id => $sub_std){
 $count_match[$id] = 0;
 // now, check for each objects 
 // you can use an other loop with in_array, array_intersect 
 // or any other way
 foreach($the_array as $word_search)
 {
   // for each word you're looking for, add +1
   if (in_array($word_search, $sub_std->words))
     $count_match[$id] ++;
 }
}
// here, $count_match is an array you can sort by best match or whatever you want
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning using a defined class instead of relying on the stdClass.

Comment: Is that correct syntax for FOR?

Comment: not at all sorry ! it was not for but `foreach` (that works for classes too :)

Comment: figured it out :) it works like charm... +1 and selected answer.

Comment: p.s. array_intersect doesn't work in your example. But in_array is enough anyways.

Comment: yeah, array_intersect needs some improvements, that's why I used this

Answer (score 0):

Try out `array_intersect()` :

```
$output = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: But I've two very different looking arrays.

Comment: Post the code you tried. Using foreach() with array_intersect (and counting the matches) should yield the results you're looking for.